# Why does subprocess.Popen use an old version of vim?

Tags: python, vim

When I run `vi --version`, I see `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3` and yet when I run the following script, it prints that I have version 7.2. Why?

The `pathname` is `vi`. `which vi` prints `/usr/local/bin/vim` and that `--version` is `7.3`.
`which gvim` prints `/usr/bin/gvim`, and that `--version` prints a newer version of vim as well.

`echo $EDITOR` prints `vi`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import os.path
import subprocess
import tempfile


def exec_vimcmd(commands, pathname='', error_stream=None):
"""Run a list of Vim 'commands' and return the commands output."""
try:
    perror = error_stream.write
except AttributeError:
    perror = sys.stderr.write

if not pathname:
    pathname = os.environ.get('EDITOR', 'gvim')

args = [pathname, '-u', 'NONE', '-esX', '-c', 'set cpo&vim']
fd, tmpname = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix='runvimcmd', suffix='.clewn')
commands.insert(0,  'redir! >%s' % tmpname)
commands.append('quit')
for cmd in commands:
    args.extend(['-c', cmd])

output = f = None
try:
    try:
        print "args are"
        print args
        subprocess.Popen(args).wait()
        f = os.fdopen(fd)
        output = f.read()
        print "output is"
        print output
        print "that's the end of the output"
    except (OSError, IOError), err:
        if isinstance(err, OSError) and err.errno == errno.ENOENT:
            perror("Failed to run '%s' as Vim.\n" % args[0])
            perror("Please set the EDITOR environment variable or run "
                            "'pyclewn --editor=/path/to/(g)vim'.\n\n")
        else:
            perror("Failed to run Vim as:\n'%s'\n\n" % str(args))
            perror("Error; %s\n", err)
        raise
finally:
    if f is not None:
        f.close()

exec_vimcmd(['version'])
```

The args printed are

```
['vi', '-u', 'NONE', '-esX', '-c', 'set cpo&vim', '-c', 'redir! >/var/folders/86/062qtcyx2rxbnmn8mtpkyghs0r0r_z/T/runvimcmducLQCe.clewn', '-c', 'version', '-c', 'quit']
```

Comment: What is the output of `print args`?

Answer (score 1):

Find out what value is being assigned to `pathname`, and see if it agrees with `which vim` or `which gvim` entered at the command prompt. Your script is looking at your `$EDITOR` environment variable, but when you run `(g)vim` from the command line it searches your `$PATH` to find the first hit. For example, you may be running `/opt/local/bin/vim` from the CLI, but `/usr/bin/vim` from your script.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. pathname is vi. which vi is /usr/local/bin/vim. which givm is /usr/bin/gvim. $EDITOR is vi.

Comment: are there any other (g)vi(m) binaries in your path, perhaps `/usr/bin/vi` or something like that? Somehow Python is using a different search path than your shell. What happens if you set `$EDITOR` to `/usr/local/bin/vim`?